# UIAlertView delegate method clickedButtonAtIndex: is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uialertview

I have a class `MyClass` and I want to set it as the delegate of the UIAlertView. My code is

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation MyClass
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView*)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (buttonIndex == 1) {

NSLog(@"Clicked button at Index 1");

}

else {
NSLog(@"Whatever");
}

}
@end
```

and In the ViewController.m

```
#import "MyClass"
@interface ViewController() {
}

@end
static MyClass *mc;

@implementation ViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad {

  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:mc cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", @"nice"];
   [alert show];
}
@end
```

when I run the app, the alert appears but when I click on button at index 1 or any other one nothing happens.
So how to fix this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: `alertView(UIAlertView*)alertView`: Shouldn't compile, missing a ":". And is `mc` nil?

Comment: @Larme This is not the real code, this is just an example that I've just wrote here so it may have some mistakes.And MyClass is a new class with no custom initialization so it's nil.

Comment: If `mc` is `nil`, how do you want it to be the delegate and responds to it?

Comment: It worked after allocating and initializing it. thanks :)

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is not a good place to show an alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually alloc/init `mc`

Something like (don't forget to call super):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  if (mc == nil)
     mc = [MyClass alloc] init];
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:mc cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", @"nice"];
  [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Maybe move the presentation to later in the view controller's lifecycle too.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the delegate to be an object that it doesn't appear that you've initialized.  Make sure that `mc` isn't nil, and if it is, add an alloc/init line to create `mc` before you create the alert.

Comment: Awesome!  :)  Be sure to label the question as Answered, and up-vote any answers that helped.